# How to loop in a file from the middle.. (using a condition)

Tags: python, file, loops

How would i start a loop on a condition:
for example.

```
I have following contents in a file:
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5
text6
```

now the problem is i want to start the loop form text3 until text5...How can i start this loop. 
Does it need a sperate parameter or a different argument?

OKay, the answers are good:

But what if it was a larger file ?

Like

```
'A'
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5
text6

'B'
text7
text8
text9
text10
```

And we wanna loop from 'B' to the blank line??

I would appreciate all the help.. thanks

Comment: You're going to have to explain what you mean by "loop in a file".  Are you trying to reread selected lines? What code do you have so far?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "middle"? Do you want to skip a certain number of lines? Or a certain number of bytes from the start? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

if each line share a fix length , I think you may try file.seek(n)

```
>>> f.seek(5)     # Go to the 6th byte in the file
```

else

```
n = start_line
m = end_line

with open("text_file","r") as f
    for i in f.readlines()[n:m]:
        print i
```

if the file is large, we need a counter and using "open" function, that will read a single line per time

```
fh = open("file","r")
start_piont = 0
n = 6     #starting row
m = 16    #ending row
row_list = [] # result row list
for l in fh:   # read a single line per time
    start_piont = start_piont + 1
    if start_piont >= n :
        row_list.append(l)
    if start_piont > m:
        break
```

Comment: But what if it was a larger file.

Comment: for a not perfect workaround , using iteration and add a counter to remind the programm when hitting the N(starting row), I've update my code

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to skip over reading the first two lines of the file w/o processing them?

```
f = open('filename')
f.readline()
f.readline()
lines=f.readines()
for line in lines:
    do whatever...
```

you could use "seek" but if the lines are different lengths, you will not know the position to seek to.

Comment: "do whatever" means process the rest of the lines.  The poster's question is SO vague (as you can see by all the answers that say "assuming...".)  It would be nice if the post asked a specific question with well-define bounds.  See my posted questions, for example.  Asking a well-crafted question is 99% of the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

1) you want to reach a specific identifier, e.g. 'B'
  2) The file has a sorted structure, e.g. 'A' ...  'B' ... 'C' ... etc

You could try binary search with seek.

The high level idea would be:

1) Get the size of the file.
2) Seek to the middle of the file.
   Start reading lines till you hit an identifier, say found_identifier.
   if found_identifier > target_identifier: seek in the middle of the upper part.
   if found_identifier < target_identifier: seek in the middle of the lower part.
   if found_identifier == target_identifier: you reached the right region in your file.

This approach should do log2(size of file) seeks, which should be faster than sequentially reading very large files...

Hope this helps...

Comment: Seek works with bytes, so that length of lines is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

> And we wanna loop from 'B' to the blank line??

I assume you want to read lines starting from line with sole "B" and stopping at the first blank line. And you don't want to read the whole file into memory:

```
with open("your_file.txt") as file:
     start = False
     for line in file:
         if start:
            if not line.strip(): # blank 
               break # done
            process(line)
         elif line.strip() == "B":
            start = True
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
example="""'A'
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5
text6

'B'
text7
text8
text9
text10

line11
line12
line13
""".splitlines()     # standin for a file...

flag=False
for line in example:
    if line.strip()=="'B'":
        flag=True
    if flag==True and line.strip():
        print line
    if flag==True and not line.strip():
        flag=False
```

prints:

```
'B'
text7
text8
text9
text10
```

Comment: what goes before .splitlines()?

Comment: @user1853961: `.splitlines()` is splitting the [multi-line string literal](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) that starts and ends with `"""`. The result is that multi-line string is split on new lines into a list of string in `example` which is similar to what a file looks like.